# Angular11+Rxjs+openapi-generator-cli subscribe can't reach subfield

Tags: angular, rxjs, openapi-generator-cli

The project is to consume a weather API. I use openapi-generator-cli to generate the typescript api client code.

The generated service class

```
/**
     * This method retrieves weather forecast
     * @param authorization Auth Token
     * @param transactionId Transaction Id
     * @param airportCode Airport Code
     * @param forecastInterval forecastInterval
     * @param observe set whether or not to return the data Observable as the body, response or events. defaults to returning the body.
     * @param reportProgress flag to report request and response progress.
     */
    public getForecastUsingGET(authorization: string, transactionId: string, airportCode: Array<string>, forecastInterval?: number, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<WeatherForecastResp>;
    public getForecastUsingGET(authorization: string, transactionId: string, airportCode: Array<string>, forecastInterval?: number, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<HttpResponse<WeatherForecastResp>>;
    public getForecastUsingGET(authorization: string, transactionId: string, airportCode: Array<string>, forecastInterval?: number, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<HttpEvent<WeatherForecastResp>>;
    public getForecastUsingGET(authorization: string, transactionId: string, airportCode: Array<string>, forecastInterval?: number, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<any> {
      ......
      return this.httpClient.get<WeatherForecastResp>(`${this.configuration.basePath}/forecasts`,
            {
                params: queryParameters,
                responseType: <any>responseType,
                withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
                headers: headers,
                observe: observe,
                reportProgress: reportProgress
            }
        );
    }
```

Model class

```
export interface WeatherForecastResp { 
    weatherForecasts?: Array<WeatherForecast>;
}
export interface WeatherForecast { 
    forecastInterval?: Forecasts;
}
export interface Forecasts { 
    metadata?: Metadata;
    forecasts?: Array<Forecast>;
}
export interface Forecast { 
    cityName?: string;
    countryCode?: string;
    dayNum?: string;
    highTemperatureC?: string;
    highTemperatureF?: string;
    locationId?: string;
    lowTemperatureC?: string;
    lowTemperatureF?: string;
    ......
}
```

Then when I call the API service, I can see the root data object, but when I try to call the sub-object, it returns undefined.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'angular-weather-widget';  
  constructor(private forecastService: ForecastService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.forecastService.getForecastUsingGET("","",["ATL"]).subscribe(
      body => {
        //this.fieldStr = body.weatherForecasts?.[0].forecastInterval?.forecasts?.[0].dayNum;
        console.log(typeof(body));
        console.log("body: " + JSON.stringify(body));
        console.log("WeatherForecast: " + body.weatherForecasts?.length); // value is undefined
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error caught at Subscriber " + err)
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Processing Complete. " )
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Question

1. How I can access the data in Forecast(3 level nested) and
   display in the html? I try using '?' and '!' such as
   `body.weatherForecasts?.[0].forecastInterval?.forecasts?.[0].dayNum!`
   but always get `undefined` back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because you misspelled the property name `WeatherForecasts` which starts with a capital letter. Have a look at the output from `console.log("body: " + JSON.stringify(body));`

Comment: @kruschid You are right, for some reason, the response has upper case `WeatherForecasts` but in the model it is lower case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by mismatched capital letters. This is little bit annoying if you only focus on the API contract and model.